# On the group cohomology $H^1(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}), \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{C}))$

Tags: complex-analysis, homology-cohomology

Inspired by an answer to

[What is the intuition between 1-cocycles (group cohomology)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312515/what-is-the-intuition-between-1-cocycles-group-cohomology),

one may wonder what are the meromorphic functions $f \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{C})$ for which there exists a function $j = j(f): SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \times \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that satisfies

$$f\left(\frac{az + b}{cz + d}\right) = j(a, b, c, d, z)f(z),$$ when $ad - bc = 1$. In particular, are all such $f$ necessarily modular? Also, what is the cohomology group

$$H^1(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}), \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{C}))?$$

(I suspect this might be known or addressed somewhere).

Comment: So $j$ is an [automorphy factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphic_factor)

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287960/