# Intuition for cohomology of groups

Tags: intuition, group-cohomology

I just finish reading a pdf about group cohomology that explain a lot about it. It goes from the definition to Galois's cohomology.
But there is one think I would like to know and I think I haven't enough read about cohomology to know : What is the intuition behind all of this theory ?
If someone could explain me or just give me some references I would appreciate.
Thank you very much !

Comment: This is not intuition, but possible motivation : if you are interested in computing the rational points of an elliptic curve $E$, say $y^2 = x^3 - k$, then you notice that $E(\Bbb Q)$ is the set of invariants of $E(\overline{\Bbb Q})$ under the action of the absolute Galois group. Taking these invariants provides a left-exact functor [unfortunately it is not right exact, i.e. invariants don't commute with quotients], whose right derived functors are precisely giving group cohomology (here Galois cohomology).

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10879/intuition-for-group-cohomology, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312515/what-is-the-intuition-between-1-cocycles-group-cohomology/636981

Comment: Actually I don't know what is an Elliptic curve neither than an absolute Galois group, is this hard to understand ?

Comment: Dear @Pierre21, the equation $y^2 = x^3 - k$ (for a fixed non-zero integer $k$) is the equation of an elliptic curve, and $E(\Bbb Q)$ is the set of pairs $(x,y)$ satisfying this equation (there is just a "subtelty" with the "point at infinity"). This is not hard at all! (What is harder is to have a group structure on $E(\Bbb Q)$, though).

Comment: Hmm okay thank you ! But like is this that type of oservation that lead the mathematician to construct all this structure ?

Comment: Dear @Pierre21, some of the _historical_ motivations of group cohomology seem to be explained [here](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~kbrown/papers/cohomology_hangzhou.pdf), on p. 1.

Comment: Thank you very much I will read this in details !